# Python: grouping items already in a list and reverse them

Tags: python, list, count, nested, reverse

I have a binary file likes this:

```
00 01 02 04 03 03 03 03 00 05 06 03 03 03 03 03 00 07 03 03 03 03 03 03 ...
```

and I would like to make groups of 8 items each

```
[00 01 02 04 03 03 03 03] [00 05 06 03 03 03 03 03] [00 07 03 03 03 03 03 03]...
```

and then reverse the items inside each group like this:

```
[03 03 03 03 04 02 01 00] [03 03 03 03 03 06 05 00] [03 03 03 03 03 03 07 00]
```

I tried reverse() but it reverse all the list.

I've imagined something like that: in a loop I should count until 8 (or 7), make a group, reverse it, and then increment the row, count 8, reverse and so on but I am not able to code that.

I have tried

```
i=0
for item in (list_reverse):
    i+=1
    if i>8:
        list_reverse.reverse()
        i=0
```

but it doesn't work.

Maybe I should try a nested loop?

Comment: Is you data a list of strings or a list of lists of strings?

Comment: what do you mean "it reverses all the list"?

Comment: My datas are a list of images actually and by "it reverses all the list" I mean that the last item become the first, the penultimate become the second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` the strings, then loop through it.

```py
t = """00 01 02 04 03 03 03 03
00 05 06 03 03 03 03 03
00 07 03 03 03 03 03 03"""
out = ""
lines = t.split("\n")
for n, line in enumerate(lines):
    lst = line.split(" ")
    c = 0
    reversed_lst = ""
    while c < len(lst):
        reversed_lst += (lst[len(lst)- c -1]) + " "; c+=1 
    if n != len(lines) - 1:
        out += reversed_lst + "\n"
    else:
        out += reversed_lst
print(out)
```

Output:

```
03 03 03 03 04 02 01 00 
03 03 03 03 03 06 05 00 
03 03 03 03 03 03 07 00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good usecase for Python's builtin [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray). First, you can open the binary input file and use a `bytearray` to store its contents:

```
with open("binary.file", "rb") as f:
    bytes = bytearray(f.read())
```

Then, we'll use your algorithm to loop over the bytes and store them in a variable called `group` (which is also a `bytearray`) every 8 iterations:

```
i = 0
groups = []
group = bytearray()
for byte in bytes:
    i += 1
    group.append(byte)
    if i == 8:
        groups.append(group)
        i = 0
        group = bytearray()
```

Just as quick sanity check, test the value of variable `i` because if it's not zero by now the final group would be less than 8 bytes long:

```
if i != 0:
    raise EOFError("Input file does not align to 8 byte boundary!")
```

Finally, we'll reverse each group and print the output:

```
for group in groups:
    group.reverse()

print(groups)
```

Depending on your usecase, you could also concatenate the reversed bytes and store them in another file or even overwrite the same file. Although my guess is if you would do that to any ordinary binary files like a JPEG or an EXE you will break them completely. Luckily, you could run the program again to restore them!